# sending backend file and formBuilder

Tags: angular, http, post

How to send to backend file and formBuilder

my try

```
    save(form) { // form == formBuilder

        const uploadData = new FormData();
        if (this.selectedFile) {
          uploadData.append('myFile', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
        }
        this.professorService.save(uploadData,form)
    }
```

service.ts

```
save(form,fb) {
    let params: HttpParams = undefined
    params = new HttpParams().set('fb', fb)    
    return this.http.post(`${BE_API}/professor.php?action=save`, form,{ params: params})
      .subscribe((data) => {
        if (data['success'] == 'ok') {
        }
        console.log(data);
      }, (error) => {
      });
  }
```

In the backend the fb (formBuilder) is arriving with string " "

Output console

```
array(12) {
  ["fb"]=>
  string(15) "[object Object]"
...
}
```